# How to speed up simple UPDATE query with millions of rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

How can I speed up this rather simple UPDATE query?  It's been running for over 5 hours!

I'm basically replacing SourceID in a table by joining on a new table that houses the Old and New IDs.  All these fields are VARCHAR(72) and must stay that way.

Pub_ArticleFaculty table has 8,354,474 rows (8.3 million).  ArticleAuthorOldNew has 99,326,472 rows (99.3  million) and only the 2 fields you see below.

There are separate non-clustered indexes on all these fields.  Is there a better way to write this query to make it run faster?

```
UPDATE PF
        SET PF.SourceId = AAON.NewSourceId
    FROM AA..Pub_ArticleFaculty PF WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN AA2..ArticleAuthorOldNew AAON WITH (NOLOCK)  
                   ON AAON.OldFullSourceId = PF.SourceId
```

Comment: Once it's finished, will you ever have to do it again?

Comment: What recovery mode is your database in (FULL, SIMPLE, BULK-LOGGED)?  Is your transaction log adequately sized?

Comment: That database is in FULL recovery mode now. It's ok to take off for an hour or so maybe since it's in a test environment. I won't have to run this again, and I'm not sure how to tell if the log is adequately sized. I don't even care much about logging since we have a DB backup if needed.

Comment: I think your query is running slower and slower, I've come across a similar issue before, and what I did is reindex the table

Comment: Also, try updating the data partially, see if this helps.

Comment: Use `sp_who2` to find out right now what you're waiting for

Comment: I don't see anything that's blocking it or anything else when checking sp_who2.

Comment: I've turned on BULK LOGGING recovery mode.  Hopefully that speeds it up?  I'm reluctant to move data around into temp tables and truncate it because it's so many records and the table I'm updating has over 30 fields (I didn't design it!).  This sucks... :(

Comment: Why is it slow? The first thing you need to do is get the execution plan and find out what operation is causing the problem. Without that, all you are doing is blindly guessing.

Comment: So in sp+Who2 what does it say it's doing? run it a few times to get an idea. If you're not interested in point-in-time restores, change the recovery model to simple.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In my experience, looping your update so that it acts on small a numbers of rows each iteration is a good way to go. The ideal number of rows to update each iteration is largely dependent on your environment and the tables you're working with. I usually stick around 1,000 - 10,000 rows per iteration.

**Example**

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1000 -- Set the batch size (number of rows to affect each time through the loop).
WHILE (1=1) BEGIN

    UPDATE PF
    SET NewSourceId = 1
    FROM AA..Pub_ArticleFaculty PF WITH (NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN AA2..ArticleAuthorOldNew AAON WITH (NOLOCK)  
                       ON AAON.OldFullSourceId = PF.SourceId
    WHERE NewSourceId IS NULL -- Only update rows that haven't yet been updated.

    -- When no rows are affected, we're done!
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        BREAK
END
SET ROWCOUNT 0 -- Reset the batch size to the default (i.e. all rows).
GO
```

Comment: thanks for the example, but we need to use TOP syntax in the recent release of SQL Server. 

Using SET ROWCOUNT will not affect DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements in a future release of SQL Server. Avoid using SET ROWCOUNT with DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. For a similar behavior, use the TOP syntax. For more information, see TOP (Transact-SQL).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#:~:text=Using%20SET%20ROWCOUNT,Transact%2DSQL).

Answer (score 4):

If you are resetting all or almost all of the values, then the `update` will be quite expensive.  This is due to logging and the overhead for the updates.

One approach you can take instead is `insert` into a temporary table, then truncate, then re-insert:

```
select pf.col1, pf.col2,  . . . ,
       coalesce(aaon.NewSourceId, pf.sourceid) as SourceId
into temp_pf
from AA..Pub_ArticleFaculty PF LEFT JOIN
     AA2..ArticleAuthorOldNew AAON 
     on AAON.OldFullSourceId = PF.SourceId;

truncate table AA..Pub_ArticleFaculty;

insert into AA..Pub_ArticleFaculty
    select * from temp_pf;
```

Note:  You should either be sure that the columns in the original table match the temporary table or, better yet, list the columns explicitly in the `insert`.

I should also note that the major benefit is when your recovery mode is simple or bulk-logged.  The reason is that logging for the truncate, `select into`, and `insert . . . select` is minimal (see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244(v=sql.105).aspx)).  This savings on the logging can be very significant.

Comment: will BULK-LOGGED RECOVERY mode help to reduce logging as well?  I can try this approach you mentioned, but not sure I feel good about truncating the table as it has over 30 fields (not my design, have pity on me...haha!).  Too much room for error, I think.

Comment: @AndyDesRosiers . . . You can put the data into a temporary table and then rename tables, instead of inserting the values back in.  That step is there to preserve constraints, triggers, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I would

- Disable the index on  PF.SourceId
- Run the update
- Then rebuild the index

I don't get the `NOLOCK` on the table you are updating

```
UPDATE PF
SET PF.SourceId = AAON.NewSourceId
FROM AA..Pub_ArticleFaculty PF 
INNER JOIN AA2..ArticleAuthorOldNew AAON WITH (NOLOCK)  
        ON AAON.OldFullSourceId = PF.SourceId 
       AND PF.SourceId <> AAON.NewSourceId
```

Comment: I've taken off the NOLOCK now and also changed the DB to run in SIMPLE fully recovery mode temporarily as well as adding a WHERE LIKE clause to run data in chunks in separate queries.  These seems to have sped it up a lot.  I'm curious about disabling the index though...I thought the whole purpose of it was to make searching and joining faster?  But is it because we are updating that field, that it's making things run slower with the index on?

Comment: Index maintenance takes time.   What does it hurt to try?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to comment on the question. So I'm adding it as an answer. Can you check the basics

1. Are there any triggers on the table? If there are, there will be additional overhead when you are updating rows.
2. Are there indexes on the joining columns?
3. In other cases, does the system perform well? Verify that the system have enough power.

But 8 million records are not much to run more than 1 minute max if processing properly. An execution time of 5 hrs indicates there is a problem somewhere else.